# How to combine 2 int value columns to varchar with specified length

Tags: sql-server

i would like to combine this two int columns into one:

```
Month   Year
1       2017  
2       2016
12      2016
```

i used `SELECT CAST(Year AS nvarchar(20)) + '-' + CAST(Month AS nvarchar(20)) AS newcolumn from table_name`

however, the result that i got is

```
newcolumn
2017-1
2016-2
2016-10
```

my desired result is

```
newcolumn
2017-01
2016-02
2016-10
```

im using ms sql server.

Thanks

Comment: What version of sql server? Bennjoe's answer will work; SQL Server 2012 and after has additional options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pad the month format so that it is forced to display 2 numbers.

```
SELECT CAST(Year AS nvarchar(20)) + '-' 
+ RIGHT('00' + CAST(Month AS nvarchar(20)),2) AS newcolumn from table_name
```

Sample with Getdate():

```
SELECT CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) as nvarchar(20)) + '-' +
       RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) as NVARCHAR(2)),2)
```